# accessing values from an object model using 'controller as' $scope angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I'm attempting to grab the user.firstName and user.lastName, add a watch collection to those models, and spit back out a userName.

I can't seem to communicate between the two, I think I'm using scope and self incorrect.  I'm pretty new and misunderstanding the two concepts.

And because I'm getting an error, what is the proper way to grab `lastName` and `firstName` from the `$user` object, and spit back out something to the view?

I'm using the 'controller as' syntax.  Ty for any guidance.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="ctrl.user.firstName" required>
<input ng-model="ctrl.user.lastName" required>
<input type="text" value="{{userName}}" name="user_name" ng-model="ctrl.user.userName">
```

**JS**

```
var self = this
$scope.$watchCollection('[user.firstName, user.lastName]', function () {
    if (self.user.firstName != '' && self.user.lastName != '') {
        $scope.userName = self.user.firstName + '_' + self.user.lastName + '_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
        $scope.user.userName.$setViewValue($scope.userName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$watchCollection is evaluated against scope, so you need:

```
var self = this
self.user = {};
$scope.$watchCollection('[ctrl.user.firstName, ctrl.user.lastName]', function () {
    if (self.user.firstName != '' && self.user.lastName != '') {
        $scope.userName = self.user.firstName + '_' + self.user.lastName + '_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
        self.user.userName.$setViewValue($scope.userName);
    }
});
```

Also, I don't think you need to worry about using $setViewValue, just change to:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[ctrl.user.firstName, ctrl.user.lastName]', function () {
    if (self.user.firstName != '' && self.user.lastName != '') {
        self.user.userName = self.user.firstName + '_' + self.user.lastName + '_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
    }
});
```

and your html to:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" ng-model="ctrl.user.userName">
```

the "name" attribute is only used if you are embedding the input in a form.   If that is the case, you can access for validation, etc, with

```
$scope.formName.user_name
```

Comment: self.user.firstName is producing an error, is it because it's not instantiated before the watch happens??

Comment: Yes, you need to initialized the user object before referencing a property of it.  See update